# How to add custom fields to Roster in XMPPFramework in iOS and Openfire?

Tags: ios, iphone, openfire, xmppframework

We are using [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) in iOS and using Openfire on the server side. So far we are able to connect to server and implement one to one chat.

Now we want to add new properties to Roster in iOS as well as on server. 
For example,
Email
Phone
Location

Is that possible? If possible how?

I tried checking but nothing came out regarding this on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Pratik